# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to make a simple app, but everytime I try to run the app, I get this error.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.>com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\Alejandro\Dropbox\2º DAM\AndroidStudioProjectsDropbox\FastyFast\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\Alejandro\Dropbox\2º DAM\AndroidStudioProjectsDropbox\FastyFast\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
>   Error Code:
>       1
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: C:\Users\Alejandro\Dropbox\2Âº DAM\AndroidStudioProjectsDropbox\FastyFast\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug: file not found
>           at com.android.dex.util.FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.java:51)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:169)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Alejandro\Dropbox\2Âº DAM\AndroidStudioProjectsDropbox\FastyFast\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-annotations-21.0.3-b29fd01b30007e41669b44d2e19fb39eea844240.jar (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Alejandro\Dropbox\2Âº DAM\AndroidStudioProjectsDropbox\FastyFast\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-21.0.3-5a0c9ff4d81e7e53b50296e4e2549fc036b4b3db.jar (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Alejandro\Dropbox\2Âº DAM\AndroidStudioProjectsDropbox\FastyFast\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-1a3933f3cfbb63995646d20c10e8ee01b7f2eac5.jar (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Alejandro\Dropbox\2Âº DAM\AndroidStudioProjectsDropbox\FastyFast\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-1337a4751778935a1a6ca6cffc12c9f23e5cc37f.jar (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       5 errors; aborting

I've being searching for a solution, but I found nothing.

Here's my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fasty.fastyfast"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

And this is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fasty.fastyfast" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

It doesen't crash when I sync. with Gradle Files but I try to run the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C:\Users\Alejandro\Dropbox\2º DAM\AndroidStudioProjectsDropbox\FastyFast\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\Alejandro\Dropbox\2º DAM\AndroidStudioProjectsDropbox\FastyFast\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt

º this character is not recognise by Android or the class. I will suggest you to change the name of the project and put something without special characters.

Comment: thanks.. my " ™ " in folder name made me a lot of problems :P

Answer (score 0):

I can see:

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Alejandro\Dropbox\2Âº DAM\AndroidStudioProjectsDropbox\FastyFast\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-21.0.3-5a0c9ff4d81e7e53b50296e4e2549fc036b4b3db.jar

It looks to me like `2Âº` should not be in the path. Strange encoding.